# Phrase to acronym in C from exercism.io

Tags: beginner, c, programming-challenge, strings

I am learning C and doing challenges like those found on exercism.io and the various data structure & algorithm sites.

I have a sense that while this works and it makes sense to me that it can be improved and probably isn't how a professional C programmer would have solved it.

Interested if this would pass a code review in a professional setting and if not, why not.

Problem URL: [Convert a phrase to its acronym](https://exercism.org/tracks/c/exercises/acronym)

> Convert a phrase to its acronym.
>
> Techies love their TLA (Three Letter Acronyms)!
>
> Help generate some jargon by writing a program that converts a long name like Portable Network Graphics to its acronym (PNG).

acronym.h

```c
#ifndef ACRONYM_H
#define ACRONYM_H

char *abbreviate(const char *phrase);

#endif
```

```c
#include "acronym.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *abbreviate(const char *phrase) {

  // Return NULL for NULL or empty phrase
  if (phrase == NULL || strlen(phrase) == 0) {
    return NULL;
  }

  size_t phrase_length = strlen(phrase) - 1;
  size_t acronym_index = 0;
  size_t phrase_index = 0;

  // The acronym will not be longer than the phrase length.
  char *acronym = malloc(phrase_length * sizeof(char));

  // The first letter of the phrase is the first initial in the acronym.
  acronym[acronym_index] = toupper(phrase[phrase_index]);

  acronym_index++;
  phrase_index++;

  while (phrase[phrase_index] != '\0') {
    // At the end of the string, add a null terminator.
    if (phrase_index == phrase_length) {
      acronym[acronym_index] = '\0';
      acronym_index++;
      phrase_index++;
      break;
    }

    char letter = phrase[phrase_index];
    char next_letter = phrase[phrase_index + 1];

    // If letter is not an apostrophe or alpha character, but the next one is,
    // found a word boundary and the next charcter is part of the acronym.
    if (letter != '\'' && !isalpha(letter) && isalpha(next_letter)) {
      acronym[acronym_index] = toupper(next_letter);

      acronym_index++;
      phrase_index++;
    }

    phrase_index++;
  }

  return acronym;
}
```

[Github full solution including tests](https://github.com/olepunchy/exercism-c-solutions/tree/main/acronym)

Comment: Your code returns an unterminated string. You should add ‘\0’ at then end of `acronym`. We usually only review working code. This is what I got for `United States of America` : `USOA═════════════²²²²`

Comment: Did this code pass the tests?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, yes it passes all the tests.

Answer (score 1):

I'll show you what I would write first:

```
char *abbreviate(const char *phrase) {
  assert(phrase);

  char *acronym = malloc(strlen(phrase) / 2 + 1);
  if (!acronym) {
    return NULL;
  }

  char previous = ' ';
  size_t len = 0;

  for (size_t i = 0; phrase[i]; i++) {
    char current = phrase[i];
    if (previous != '\'' && !isalpha(previous) && isalpha(current)) {
      acronym[len++] = toupper(current);
    }
    previous = current;
  }

  acronym[len++] = '\0';
  return realloc(acronym, len);
}
```

First of all, I require the function to be called with a non-NULL pointer, as passing a NULL pointer would probably be a programming error on the side of the caller. I check for it using an `assert()` call, which can be compiled out in release builds.

Then there are various ways to allocate memory; you could start with a small buffer and grow it if necessary, or start with the maximum size the acronym could be, which is only half of the size of the original phrase. Don't forget to check that `malloc()` succeeded, and handle it returning `NULL` in some way.

Instead of comparing the current character with the next character, I compare the current one with the previous one. This is the main reason why my code is short; I don't have to check that we don't already are on the last character, and by carefully initializing `current`, the first alpha character in `phrase` will correctly be the first one in the output. Note that your code would happily copy the first character of phrase into the acronym, even if it  shouldn't have.

Finally, after ensuring the acronym is properly terminated with a NUL-byte, I shrink the allocated memory to the minimum necessary for the acronym; this avoids wasting memory. (Technically, you should check the return value of `realloc()` since it might return `NULL`, but I'm abusing my years of programming experience here and just assume that never happens if you shrink instead of grow.)

Note that this version might return an empty string if there were no alpha characters in the input. You may or may not want this behavior. The upshot of this is that this function will always return a valid string, except in case memory allocation failed. The caller can still easily check if it is empty. If you want it to return `NULL`, I suggest doing that at the end like so:

```
if (len) {
  acronym[len++] = '\0';
  return realloc(acronym, len);
} else {
  free(acronym);
  return NULL;
}
```

I would add more corner cases to your test suite, like inputs that start with spaces and ones that only consist of non-alpha characters.

Comment: Thank you, learned a lot from your reply and it all makes sense. Appreciate it.

Comment: I remember, many years ago, that there was a problem if you tried to `realloc` or `free` memory allocated by `strdup` in MSVC debug build. I suppose it could also fail if your heap is corrupted.

Comment: @JohanduToit That happened if you mixed debug and non-debug objects. I don't see how that is relevant here though, since `strdup()` is not used.

Answer (score 0):

I would have created something like the following which allows for better error handling and have the output buffer declared on the stack.

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum AbbreviationErrors
{
    phraseIsNull = 1,
    bufferTooSmall = 2,
    noLettersFound = 3
};

int abbreviate(const char* phrase, char* buf, const size_t bufSize)
{
    if (phrase == NULL)
        return phraseIsNull;
    int inAlpha = 0;
    char prevChar = 0;
    char* dst = buf;
    for (const char* ptr = phrase; *ptr; ptr++)
    {
        if (isalpha(*ptr))
        {
            if (inAlpha == 0 && prevChar != '\'')
            {
                if (dst - buf >= bufSize)
                    return bufferTooSmall;
                *dst++ = toupper(*ptr);
                inAlpha = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            inAlpha = 0;
        }
        prevChar = *ptr;
    }
    if (dst == buf)
        return noLettersFound;
    if (dst - buf >= bufSize)
        return bufferTooSmall;
    *dst = '\0';
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char test[] = "Hailey's Comet";
    static const size_t bufLen = 80;
    char buf[bufLen];
    int result = abbreviate(test, buf, bufLen);
    if (result == 0)
        printf("abbreviation = '%s'\n", buf);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This fails the test for a string like "Hailey's Comet", but did learn from your reply so appreciate it.

Comment: @olepunchy, thanks, I missed that but have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't add a comment so will try to make it as an answer.

I have tested your code that is in Git. It returns **U** when there is **USA** passed. I understand you can't compare this kind of argument with anything but may it task requirements are not clear? Since as we know (Wikipedia too):

> Phrases can consist of a **single word** or a complete sentence

Maybe in the case when there is a single word and all letters are capital leave it as is?

Comment: That output seems consistent - it's taken the first letter of the single word input, exactly as I would expect.  Are you claiming that this is incorrect?

Comment: I am not asserting anything about the correctness of the interpretation of the task conditions. I just suggest a way when there is a single word and all letters are capital leave it as is.